# Disable/Enable button conditionally based on scroll position

Tags: javascript, forms, scroll

I need to activate a checkbox once a user has scrolled to the bottom of a terms and conditions section of a form. The will be a section in part of a checkout page for ecommerce site.

I have seen arguments on here about this, but per our lawyers, it has to be this way on our site for liability reasons. An accept button at the end of the scroll box would be the last resort, as it seems to confuse some of our users who think it is not there at all no matter how much info we give them about where the button is.

I sourced [this](http://www.27seconds.com/kb/article_view.aspx?id=56) code and manipulated it to try and get it to do what I wanted. My code is listed below. It doesn't work. I have successfully disabled the button, however I cannot seem to reactivate it.

I am pretty new to javascript and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
   <head>
    <title>Scroll Test</title>
    <script language="JavaScript">
    </script>
</head>

<body>

<form name="form22" action="javascript: alert('Form submitted!');" onSubmit="return formValidation(this);">

    <p>
    License Agreement:<br />
    <textarea name="licenseAgreement" rows="10" cols="45">This is my long, long license agreement where you agree to all of my demands.

    This is my long, long license agreement where you agree to all of my demands.

    This is my long, long license agreement where you agree to all of my demands.

    This is my long, long license agreement where you agree to all of my demands.

    This is my long, long license agreement where you agree to all of my demands.

    This is my long, long license agreement where you agree to all of my demands.

    This is my long, long license agreement where you agree to all of my demands.

    This is my long, long license agreement where you agree to all of my demands.

    This is my long, long license agreement where you agree to all of my demands.

</textarea>
    </p>

    <p>
    <input name="button" type="checkbox" value="Submit" disabled> I agree
    </p>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using normal JS it adds a few things we need to check. Consider the following:

> Get the LicenseAgreementElement:

`var textElement = document.getElementsByName("licenseAgreement")[0]`

Now that we have the  element,

> Get how much the licenseAgreement textarea scrolls to.

`textElement.scrollHeight`

> We need to check if the user has scrolled the
>   entire AgreementElement ie. The `scrollTop + height` of the actual element.

`textElement.scrollTop + textElement.offsetHeight >= textElement.scrollHeight`

Attaching and event listener at the start provides us with the following:

```
document.getElementsByName("licenseAgreement")[0].addEventListener("scroll", checkScrollHeight, false);

function checkScrollHeight(){
    var textElement = document.getElementsByName("licenseAgreement")[0] 
    if ((textElement.scrollTop + textElement.offsetHeight) >= textElement.scrollHeight){
        document.getElementsByName("button")[0].disabled = false;
    }
}
```

Enabling the checkbox when the condition is met.

Finally a small time example : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GceuC/)

Comment: May I suggest another (maybe simpler) solution? Add an empty div at the bottom of the scroll-thingy, and on scroll check if it's within the screen's boundaries, if it is, it means you've scrolled far enough.

Comment: @Alxandr , feel free to add another answer. Just a note, it is a `textarea` ;)

Comment: Ah, didn't read that part xD. Anyways, I didn't bother making it another question cause I thought yours was about right, just though I'd comment that (in some cases) it can be simplified a bit :).

Comment: Thank you guys very much! I took it out of JSFiddle and into Dreamweaver and on testing in live browsers it doesn't seem to work. Firebug is telling me the error is that "document.getElementsByName("licenseAgreement")[0] is undefined" Any ideas?

Comment: @Ashley - If your markup is the same as the original post it should be fine, has anything changed? Otherwise we could try assigning `id`s instead to your elements.

Comment: @f0x I just tried changing over to id and no luck (though it more than likely is my code :( Id for license agreement is licenseAgreement, id for form is scroll, id for button is agree. JS is 'document.getElementsById("licenseAgreement")[0].addEventListener("scroll", checkScrollHeight, false);

function checkScrollHeight(){
    var agreementTextElement = document.getElementsById("licenseAgreement")[0] 
    if ((agreementTextElement.scrollTop + agreementTextElement.offsetHeight) >= agreementTextElement.scrollHeight){
        document.getElementsById("agree")[0].disabled = false;
    }
}
'

Comment: @Ashley - its just `document.getElementById('thisID').accessPropertyetc`

Comment: Fixed typo, now tests as "is null" and it breaks functionality even in JSFiddle. Would it possible to change it to a scrolling div and use the empty div that @Alexandr was talking about? Maybe I just need to dig out an old JS book and go back to basics since there is something I seem to be misunderstanding.